# Why am I getting segmentation fault after calling the pop function in my stack implementation?

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault, stack

**Pleas read to the very end**

I have a Node struct and I'm using that struct in my implementation of a stack in C: here it is:

```
char* pop(Stack* q) {
    if (isEmpty(q)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Node* temp = q->head;
    char* A = temp->data;
    q->head = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return A;
}
int isEmpty(Stack* q) {
    return (q == NULL);
}
```

I have a file where my expected output should be:

```
No items
//Push
a
b
c
//Pop
a
b
c
```

but my code yields

```
No items
//Push
a
b
c
//Pop
a
Segmentation fault
```

What is the issue with my code here?

**I am Devya Shah btw, u6480253**

Comment: Not an answer to your question but it would be much easier to follow the code if you didn't typedef structs and replaced `isEmpty` with `q == NULL`

Comment: Also provide enough code in the question to make a compiled, testable program

Comment: @OleMorud I've edited and provided my full code, I cannot provide the main function since its connected to a file which is in a format I cannot paste here.

Comment: Most likely you are not making a copy of data when you push.

Comment: how does that impact pop tho? I did make a copy in pop didnt I, called char* A, shouldn't that cover that issue?, if you mean something different, please elaborate more, thank u

Comment: data is a pointer. What does it point to? If it pointed to a temporary variable, then segfault.

Comment: The `pop` function is fundamentally wrong. Hint:  in `push` the first parameter is a `Stack**`. In `pop` the first parameter is a `Stack*`.

Comment: Perhaps just semantics, but a stack is associated with a [Last In First Out (LIFO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) data structure.. if you push `a, b, c` then you pop `c, b, a`. If you're expecting to "pop" `a, b, c` then you're trying to create a [First In First Out (FIFO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) data structure, and calling this a stack is confusing.

Comment: Your delete routine calls free on data that you did not get from malloc.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function `pop` defined like

```
char* pop(Stack* q) {
    if (q == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Node* temp = q->head;
    char* A = temp->data;
    q->head = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return A;
}
```

never sets the original pointer to the dynamically allocated stack to `NULL`. So this while loop

```
    while (!isEmpty(q)) {
        char *item = pop(q);
        printf("%s\n", item);
        free(item);
    }
```

already invokes undefined behavior.

Your stack stores pointers to string literals that have static storage duration. So this statement

```
        free(item);
```

also invokes undefined behavior.

The same problem exists in the function `delete`

```
free(curr_node->data);
```

Your stack should store dynamically allocated strings that are copies of used string literals. In this case you indeed will need to free the allocated memory for strings.

An object of the type Stack shall not be dynamically allocated inside the function `push`. The function should add new nodes to already existent stack.

Also the stack itself should not have the data member `tail`. Stack is not a queue. So it should have only the data member `head` and maybe the number of nodes in the stack.